# How can flipping a heads be 'almost surely' rather than an absolute guarantee?

Tags: probability, infinity

If you flip a coin an infinite amount of times, where heads and tails are equal probability, then there exists some sequence of flips where all tails will show up (e.g. T,T,T,T...) . It's infinitesimally small, but it exists. However this logic seems backwards to me. If we flip a coin an infinite amount of times it seems there should exist no scenario where a heads simply *can not* come up. There exists a sequence ${T,T,T,T}$... but this sequence simply doesn't exist within any possible outcomes of the coin flip game.

Another example given on wikipedia is the dart game, where if you have a unit square with each point having an equal probability of being hit, the odds of any single point being hit is 0, however it's still technically possible that you can hit that point. However with our coin flipping game, the sequence is infinite. I understand the probability space of the dart game is infinite, however by definition we have to pull one point so it can not be impossible for any point to be hit. But with the coin game is seems impossible for any one ending sequence to occur, simply because there will never be an ending sequence to our coin flips. Since there will never be any ending sequence it seems impossible to say that there exists a sequence without a heads in it.

Comment: You can't flip a coin an infinite amount of times. Try it and see.

Comment: @TonyK But if you did, then heads would surely always show up correct?

Comment: Mathematically, the sample space usually includes all possible infinite sequences of flips, including the "always tails" sequence. Your question is more intuitive.  Perhaps, instead of flipping coins one after the other, you can image a countably infinite number of planets, each one flips its coin at the same time.  Since this replaces time with space, it may be harder to make your assertion that an ending "cannot occur."

Comment: Each flip is independent so if you could continuously flip a coin for all eternity there is a possibility that you will never see a head. In fact, even where heads and tails alternate at some frequency, we would expect arbitrarily long streaks of tails. That means that not only would we expect to see a streak of a billion tails, we would expect to see streaks of tails so long that we cannot write down that number with any technology we have for expressing numbers.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to remove any event from the sample space  that has probability 0, that will not change the distribution of any random variable that you define on the sample space.  So if you want to remove the "always tails" sequence, together with the periodic oscillation sequence HTHTHT..., you can do that.  It is part of the mathemetical modeling stage. But such removals makes the problem more complicated and arguably less natural, rather than more natural.

Comment: Theoretically, it is certainly possible to always flip tails. It's also possible that I'll never lose a lottery starting tomorrow. It's just not at all *probable*.

Comment: The actual word is 'possible' and impossible'. Part of this problem is regarding the probability option, which means that even if we already flipped a coin ten octillion times and landed on TAIL, the probability for us to land on TAIL for the next flip is still 50%. Since the probability of a coin landing on HEAD still exists, the word needs to use 'almost surely' rather than 'absolute'. The 'absolute' option can exist if
a) both sides of the coin are TAIL or
b) a machine will flip the coin to give the result we want.

Comment: In probability/measure theory, we tend to regard things that have probability zero as having no consequence or impact. The fact that these points still exist in the sample space is not a problem. The words "almost surely" just tell us that we're in a *probabilistic* context, where events of measure zero are essentially ignored; specifically, I mean that most of the theorems are going to be *[up to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to)* sets of measure zero. I suppose you could come up with some alternate theory, but why bother?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can leave out from our sample space the sequence $(T,T,T,\dots)$, and that would not be a problem.

In fact, more is true.  Let $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)$ be any fixed sequence of $H$ and $T$.  Then getting exactly that sequence has probability zero.  We can leave that one out of our sample space, and it would be no problem.  Any one sequence we can leave out.  But, of course, we cannot leave all of these out simultaneously, because there would be nothing left.